# jQuery image swap if-else statement not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, if-statement

I have a problem with jQuery.

I have the following code which is inside a `$(document).ready(function() {...})`

```
 $("#one_div").hide();

 $('#button').click(function(){
        if (this.src == 'img/img1.png'){        
            this.src = 'img/img2.png';
        } 
        else {
            this.src = 'img/img1.png';
        }
        $("#one_div").slideToggle(800);
    });
```

`#button` is the ID of an image. `one_div` is the ID of a div.

Actually, clicking on the image toggles the div, but the problem is that the image is swapped only once, from `img1` to `img2`, and never switched back. What I did I do wrong?

Comment: `this.src = 'img/img1.png'` is initialization. You need `this.src == 'img/img1.png'` in the `if` condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the code inside of a `$(window).load(function() { ... });` instead to be sure the images are loaded before toggling them.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#one_div").hide();

});

$(window).load(function() {
    $('#button').click(function(){
        if ($(this).attr('src') == 'img/img1.png'){        
            $(this).attr('src', 'img/img2.png');
        } 
        else {
            $(this).attr('src', 'img/img1.png');
        }
        $("#one_div").slideToggle(800);
    });
});
```

Comment: DOesen't work. Here it is the complete code:   /n     
   
 $(window).load(function() {
   //function to hide the div
        $("#iddiv").hide();
        
    $('#idimage').click(function(){
  if (this.src == 'img/a.png'){  
   this.src = 'img/b.png';
  } 
  else {
   this.src = 'img/a.png';
  }
     $("#iddiv").slideToggle(800);
    });
 
 });

Comment: Use `$(this).attr('src', 'img/img2.png');` instead of `this.src`

Comment: Updated Answer with complete code to use.  Though you could probably place the click event within the `$(document).ready(function() {...});` call also.

Comment: Thanks, works, like a charm with: $(this).attr(). Do you know why?

Comment: Yes, `this.src` is javascript and `$(this).attr('src')` is jQuery, which is how you select the actual element that is clicked.  Javascript doesn't know what `this` is.  Normally it would, but since you are using jQuery, and need to select the actual element, you need to use `$(this)`

Answer (score 5):

You forgot your second `=`

```
(this.src == 'img/img1.png'){
```

Comment: OW, that's brudal. Since I wrote the code on the fly I forgot it, in the actual code is == (tried === aswell). Maybe I have to preload the images?

Comment: Run a `console.log(this.src)` and verify the src is actually what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you toggle the image using a class?
Code is untested, but it should become something like this:

```
$("#one_div").hide();

 $('#button').click(function(){
        this.toggleClass('active');
        if (this.hasClass('active')){     
            this.src = 'img/img2.png';
        } else {
            this.src = 'img/img1.png';
        }
        $("#one_div").slideToggle(800);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $('#button').click(function(){
    var el = document.getElementById('button');
    if (el.src == 'img/img1.png'){        
        el.src = 'img/img2.png';
    } 
    else {
        el.src = 'img/img1.png';
    }
    $("#one_div").slideToggle(800);
});
```

I think that this has returned a JQUERY object not a DOM object that you can manipulate using `.src`